# How should I JSON-serialize Enum-children?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, enums

If I write

```
import json

class Color():
    FUSCHIA = 0x00
    TURQUOISE = 0x01
    EMERALD = 0x02


def my_default_serializer(o):
    return o.__dict__


def get_colors():
    return json.dumps(
        {
            'dark_bg': True,
            'colors_batch': [Color.TURQUOISE,
                             Color.EMERALD]
        },
        default=my_default_serializer
    )

print(get_colors())
```

then I get, as expected:

```
{"dark_bg": true, "colors_batch": [1, 2]}
```

Now suppose I modernize this code by introducing `enum.Enum`. Among other things, this is handy because `Enum` will parse a string (read from a file, for example), and hence I replace the code above with:

```
import json
from enum import Enum

class Color(Enum):
    FUSCHIA = 0x00
    TURQUOISE = 0x01
    EMERALD = 0x02


def my_default_serializer(o):
    return o.__dict__


def get_colors():
    return json.dumps(
        {
            'dark_bg': True,
            'colors_batch': [Color['TURQUOISE'],
                             Color['EMERALD']]
        },
        default=my_default_serializer
    )

print(get_colors())
```

This introduces the error:

```
AttributeError: 'mappingproxy' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

(and if I don't specify the default serializer, I get `TypeError: Object of type 'Color' is not JSON serializable` ).

How should I JSON-serialize Enum-children?

Comment: can you share the definition of `big_obj` ? why `my_default_serializer` is in use?

Comment: @balderman Thanks for asking. I've now replaced the question with an identical one with a self-contained example illustrating the problem.

Comment: I managed to serialized the `Color`. See below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see below - seems to work. The idea is to override `default` method of  `JSONEncoder`, check if the incoming argument is an instance of a `Color` and handle it.

```
import json
from enum import Enum


class Color(Enum):
    FUSCHIA = 0x00
    TURQUOISE = 0x01
    EMERALD = 0x02


class EnumEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, Enum):
            return {"__enum__": str(obj)}
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)


def get_colors():
    return json.dumps(
        {
            'dark_bg': True,
            'colors_batch': [Color['TURQUOISE'],
                             Color['EMERALD']]
        }, cls=EnumEncoder
    )


print(get_colors())
```

Comment: You're code only works for the enum `Color` -- can you make it work for any enum?

Comment: @EthanFurman - Any Enum support was added.

Comment: That does it. Just one comment: We now get `{"dark_bg": true, "colors_batch": [{"__enum__": "Color.TURQUOISE"}, {"__enum__": "Color.EMERALD"}]}` instead of `{"dark_bg": true, "colors_batch": [1, 2]}`. To keep the output unchanged (so that we don't have to modify the "other side", replace `return {"__enum__": str(obj)}` with `return obj.value`.